# VBA Vlookup to populate values from sheet1 to sheet2

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Someone can tell me please why is my Func doesn't write to cells nothing?
There is no error just nothing happening.

```
Sub VL_Depositors()

On Error Resume Next

Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long
Dim Table1, Table2 As Range

Worksheets("Search term report (1)").Select
Set Table1 = Range("I2:I10")

Worksheets("MySheet").Select
Set Table2 = Range("E2:F39")

Worksheets("Search term report (1)").Select
Dept_Row = Sheet1.Range("F2").row
Dept_Clm = Sheet1.Range("F2").Column

For Each cl In Table1
    Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl,Table2, 2, False)
    Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: remove the `On Error Resume Next` and then tell us on which line it errors.

Comment: Are you trying to put values from `VLookup` in column F ? from row 2 to row 10?

Comment: From row 2 to row 10. So i changed the offset to : Cl.Offset(, 1).Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you are trying to achieve in your code is to loop through cells in `Table1` Range (from "Search term report (1)" sheet), and to see if it's found in `Table2` Range (from "MySheet" sheet).

If it's found, then put the value in Column F in "Search term report (1)" sheet, for that I am using the `Cl.Offset(, -3)`.

Also, there is a need to handle errors in case `Application.VLookup` doesn't find a value.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub VL_Depositors()

Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long
Dim Table1 As Range, Table2 As Range
Dim Cl As Range

Set Table1 = Worksheets("Search term report (1)").Range("I2:I10")
Set Table2 = Worksheets("MySheet").Range("E2:F39")

For Each Cl In Table1.Cells
    If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(Cl.Value, Table2, 2, False)) Then ' <-- VLookup was successful
        ' use offset -3 columns  >> 3 columns to the left of column "I" is column "F"
        Cl.Offset(, -3).Value = Application.VLookup(Cl.Value, Table2, 2, False)
    Else
        Cl.Offset(, -3).Value = "Value not Found!"
    End If
Next Cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai
Thanks for your help! You understood correctly, I just changed the offset property.